# Uploading a file to share point online when the url is non-standard

Tags: vba, sharepoint-2013

So I’ve been having fun with this. On my cellphone so code snippets and links are fewer than usual. I’d like to upload an excel file to share point online with vba. There are a few examples out there how to do this, but they all assume a .com or something in the url. The share point I’m working with is of the form sharepoint/sites/words/more words/file , which is driving me utterly bonkers when trying to upload any files or map it to my local drive.

How can I upload a file to sharepoint with these changes?

Comment: What did you try and what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Various error messages - bad path, error 57? I think -I’ve found that copying as path from the file explorer is giving me a new path that I’m going to try